# Using YAJL to render json in Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, yajl

I want to use YAJL to render JSON. If I `require 'yajl'` in the controller and perform a `render :json => some_hash`, will this use YAJL to encode the hash into json? Should I convert the hash to JSON using YAJL's encode method before calling render?

If not, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use require 'yajl/json_gem' on the end of environment.rb

To see if this works just inject some logging into Yajl::Encoder.encode - just for check.